# How can refresh / reload react native page activity

Tags: react-native

I have swipe component page that need to reload to see data .
I cannot use ScrollView / FlatView with swipe component (RefreshControl)
is there another way?

Answer (score 1):

If you can't wrap your component with ScrollView/FlatView, maybe the swipe component you're using can give you x/y coordinates? So you can manually calculate and trigger the reload?

If not an alternate option is to add ↻ a button somewhere at the top and handle the reload onClick?

Comment: how can make reload buttom , RefreshControl can only use in Scrollview and Flatlist

Comment: I meant you can create a usual button and show it at the top of the screen.
Not only during swipe down but always be visible.